# Bitwise operator to calculate checksum

Tags: c++, c

Am trying to come up with a C/C++ function to calculate the checksum of a given array of hex values.

char *hex = "3133455D332015550F23315D";

For e.g., the above buffer has 12 bytes and then last byte is the checksum.

Now what needs to done is, convert the 1st 11 individual bytes to decimal and then take there sum.

i.e., 31 = 49, 
      33 = 51,.....

So 49 + 51 + .....................

And then convert this decimal value to Hex. And then take the LSB of that hex value and convert that to binary.

Now take the 2's complement of this binary value and convert that to hex. At this step, the hex value should be equal to 12th byte.

But the above buffer is just an example and so it may not be correct.

So there're multiple steps involved in this.

Am looking for an easy way to do this using bitwise operators.

I did something like this, but it seems to take the 1st 2 bytes and doesn't give me the right answer.

```
int checksum (char * buffer, int size){
    int value = 0;
    unsigned short tempChecksum = 0;
    int checkSum = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < size - 1; index++) {
        value = (buffer[index] << 8) | (buffer[index]);
        tempChecksum += (unsigned short) (value & 0xFFFF);
     }

      checkSum = (~(tempChecksum & 0xFFFF) + 1) & 0xFFFF;  
}
```

I couldn't get this logic to work. I don't have enough embedded programming behind me to understand the bitwise operators. Any help is welcome.

**ANSWER**

I got this working with below changes.

```
for (int index = 0; index < size - 1; index++) {
            value = buffer[index];
            tempChecksum += (unsigned short) (value & 0xFFFF);
         }
    checkSum = (~(tempChecksum & 0xFF) + 1) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: `(buffer[index] << 8) | (buffer[index])`? Should it not be `(buffer[index] << 4) | (buffer[index + 1])`? And then do `index += 2` in the loop.

Comment: Also, should your function not *return* the checksum?

Comment: If you want a one-byte checksum, your last line should involve `(~(tempChecksum & 0xFF) + 1) & 0xFF;`.

Comment: Oh and as an addendum to my first comment, I know of *no* encodings where e.g. `1 == '1'`. So you need to convert the characters from their encoded values into proper values.

Comment: How do you read the buffer? Where do you convert the hex digits to binary values?

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  The C++ language has `std::string`, `std::vector` and `std::bitset`.

Comment: "convert to decimal and back to hex" is not a requirement. You can do addition in any base (base 2 is used by the computer)

Comment: It is not a decimal value, and you don't want to conver it to hex. It is already a hex value, and you want to convert each pair of hex gpsigits to binary.

Comment: @user207421: You'd want to convert the hex digits (e.g. the characters `"89AB"`) to integers (e.g. `0x89, 0xAB`) and not to binary (e.g. the characters `"1000100110101011"`).

Answer (score 2):

Using addition to obtain a checksum is at least weird. Common checksums use bitwise xor or full crc. But assuming it is really what you need, it can be done easily with `unsigned char` operations:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char checksum(const char *hex, int n) {
    unsigned char ck = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i+=1) {
        unsigned val;
        int cr = sscanf(hex + 2 * i, "%2x", &val);   // convert 2 hexa chars to a byte value
        if (cr == 1) ck += val;
    }
    return ck;
}
int main() {
    char hex[] = "3133455D332015550F23315D";
    char ck = checksum(hex, 11);

    printf("%2x", (unsigned) (unsigned char) ck);
    return 0;
}
```

As the operation are made on an `unsigned char` everything exceeding a byte value is properly discarded and you obtain your value (26 in your example).

Comment: I was not able to get this working. In fact i tried with much larger data involving more than 100 bytes.